# Spring boot 3.2 migration security roles is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I just migrate from Spring boot 2.7  to Spring Boot 3.2 and I am experience problem with the Security implementation of JWT.

I got this exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Set.stream()" because the return value of "com.package.app.model.User.getRoles()" is null`  as the roles in database are not missing.

I am using `JwtTokenProvider` and `JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter`

I am using this dependencies for jwt:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

There also failed test for account update service verifyAccountUpdate that state the update does not change the email(username in the case):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :expected@email.com
Actual   :is "test@email.com"
```

I am not sure really what happening if I create user the email and password are not set in the db.

When I hit endpoint its return 401 as I have `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` if I remove it its return 403

Hope is clear with the attached code. I try to follow [Spring security migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) but no luck.

Spring Security class:

```
import com.package.app.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.package.app.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        

        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());

        http.httpBasic(withDefaults()).cors(withDefaults()).headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::deny))

                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/swagger.html", "/api/v1/swagger-ui/**", "/api/v1/api-docs/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/storefront/accounts")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/platform/accounts")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(handling -> handling
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(management -> management
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter class:

````
package com.package.app.jwt;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get JWT token from http request
        String token = getTokenFromRequest(request);

        // validate token
        if (StringUtils.hasText(token) && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {

            // get username from token
            String username = jwtTokenProvider.getUsername(token);

            // load the user associated with token
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities()
            );

            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you please include the portion of your code which throws the exception ? I don't see any Set or User object in the code you provided.